# Ошибка has protected access при компиляции приложения

Tags: android, android-room

Пытаюсь вывести данные из готовой БД используя `Room` и `Paging library`.

Делал по урокам на startandroid и документации.

Но при сборке приложения появляется ошибка

> error: RusEngAdapter() has protected access in RusEngAdapter

в строке `RusEngAdapter adapter = new RusEngAdapter();` класса `MainActivity`

Почему возникает такая ошибка?

Ниже приведу все что я сделал

RusEng класс - описывает таблицу ruseng в БД

```
@Entity(tableName = "ruseng") //Описывает таблицу в БД
public class RusEng {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) //Система сама будет инкрементировать это поле в БД
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String word;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = TEXT)
    private String translation;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = INTEGER)
    private int favorites;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

    public int getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }

    public void setFavorites(int favorites) {
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        RusEng ruseng = (RusEng) obj;
        return ruseng.id == this.id && ruseng.word == this.word && ruseng.translation == this.translation;
    }

    public RusEng(int id, String word, String translation, int favorites) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
        this.translation = translation;
        this.favorites = favorites;
    }
}
```

RusEngDao

```
@Dao
public interface RusEngDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ruseng")
    DataSource.Factory<Integer, RusEng> getAllRusEngWords();
}
```

AppDatabase - класс для работы с БД

```
@Database(entities = {RusEng.class, EngRus.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    //Объявляем абстрактные методы для интерфейсов Dao
    public abstract RusEngDao rusEngDao();
    public abstract EngRusDao engRusDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "slovar.db";

    //Здесь мы работает уже с готовой БД, которая находится в папке assets
    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();
    }
}
```

RusEngViewModel

```
public class RusEngViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private RusEngDao rusEngDao;
    public LiveData<PagedList<RusEng>> rusengList;

    public RusEngViewModel(RusEngDao rusEngDao) {
        this.rusEngDao = rusEngDao;
        rusengList = new LivePagedListBuilder <>(
                rusEngDao.getAllRusEngWords(), 50).build();
    }
}
```

RusEngAdapter

```
public class RusEngAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<RusEng, RusEngAdapter.RusEngViewHolder> {

    protected RusEngAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }

    @Override
    public RusEngViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new RusEngViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RusEngViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RusEng rusEng = getItem(position);
        if(rusEng!=null) {
            holder.bindTo(rusEng);
        }
    }

    static class RusEngViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtWord, txtTranslate;

        public RusEngViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtWord = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            txtTranslate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTranslate);
        }

        public void bindTo(RusEng rusEng) {
            txtWord.setText(rusEng.getWord());
            txtTranslate.setText(rusEng.getTranslation());
        }
    }

    private static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RusEng> DIFF_CALLBACK =
            new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RusEng>() {
                // Concert details may have changed if reloaded from the database,
                // but ID is fixed.
                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(RusEng oldRusEng, RusEng newRusEng) {
                    return oldRusEng.getId() == newRusEng.getId();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(RusEng oldRusEng,
                                                  RusEng newRusEng) {
                    return oldRusEng.equals(newRusEng);
                }
            };

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private RecyclerView rvList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        rvList = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        RusEngViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RusEngViewModel.class);
        RusEngAdapter adapter = new RusEngAdapter();

        viewModel.rusengList.observe(this, pagedList -> {
            adapter.submitList(pagedList);
        });
        rvList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Если написать publuc RusEngAdapter() в адаптере то ошибка

> Process: ru.test.rusengdictionary, PID: 27798
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ru.test.rusengdictionary/ru.test.rusengdictionary.ui.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   ru.test.rusengdictionary.adapters.RusEngViewModel at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of
>   class ru.test.rusengdictionary.adapters.RusEngViewModel at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:184)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:241)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130)
>   at
>   ru.test.rusengdictionary.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   java.lang.Class has
>   no zero argument constructor at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native
>   Method) at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:182)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:241) 
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:164) 
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:130) 
>   at
>   ru.test.rusengdictionary.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52) 
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Comment: У вас действительно `protected RusEngAdapter()`, что, видимо, делать нельзя. Замените на `public` и должно заработать.

Comment: Я так тоже делал, но тогда другая ошибка. Сейчас в вопрос добавлю ошибку. В документации тоже с protected было указано. RusEngViewModel тоже по документации  написал

Comment: В ошибке у вас сказано, что класс `RusEngViewModel` должен иметь дефолтный конструктор, а у вас его нет. Надо добавить.

Comment: Я извиняюсь. А как он должен выглядеть - этот дефолтный конструктор? Везде где   я не смотрел так как у меня один конструктор. В документации тож

Comment: Ну... Я просто говорю как нужно сделать чтобы исчезла приведённая вами ошибка. Я не знаю как работают все ваши библиотеки... А дефолтный конструктор - это который без аргументов. Т.е. `public RusEngViewModel() {}`